# Persistently setting Hubot's Campfire variables on *nix

Tags: unix, github, hubot, campfire

I have successfully set up a [Hubot](http://hubot.github.com/) with variables set according to the [Campfire adapter README](https://github.com/github/hubot/wiki/Adapter%3a-Campfire), but when I restart my shell the variables are no longer set. How can I set these variables in a way that persists across shell sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that I had to save them to a file rather than just typing `export` commands in the shell, but I didn't know that it was as easy as:

1. Editing the bin/hubot file itself (I thought there must be some separate config file)
2. Simply typing the exact same export commands into the hubot file as the ones I had typed into the shell (I assumed there'd be some weird syntax, but there isn't.)